# How can I check it appears twice and keep the email address from the database in the foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have one selection from database and all records i store in variable `$list` now.. In my database i have more account with same email address how to store in variable `$list` one of this..

I have this code:

```
<?php foreach($list as $li){                    
  echo $li['email'].'<br>';
}?>
```

And in mysql i have this:

```
public function getEmailAddress(){
        $sql = "SELECT email FROM account.account";
        $stmt=$this->o_db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':apply' => $apply));

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }
```

In query mysql selection I need a condition or in php code?

Comment: if you want to prevent duplication the table i advice you to use a UNIQUE key on the email column.

Comment: Not sure want to want i have you feeling you only want duplicated emails only to be shown? In that case you need the query `SELECT email FROM  account.account GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2`.. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I would say you need the condition in the SQL, but I have no idea from your question what the condition would be other than `WHERE somthing = :apply`

Comment: I'm with @Riggs here. Your question is unclear in that respect (for me).

Comment: I want to select all email addresses once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are asking is a way to skip any duplicate email addresses, here is what you can do.

---

Just use the [DISTINCT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) keyword in your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT email FROM account.account";
```

Alternatively, you could use PHP.

```
<?php 
    $processed_emails = [];
    foreach($list as $li){
        $email = $li['email'];
        if(!in_array($email, $processed_emails)) {
            echo "{$email}<br>";
            $processed_emails[] = $email;
        }
    }
?>
```

Alternatively, you could use PHP's [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function.

```
<?php 
    $list = array_unique($list);
    foreach($list as $li){                    
        echo $li['email'].'<br>';
    }
?>
```

---

Note:

Your code is likely failing because of this: `$stmt->execute(array(':apply' => $apply));`. You are sending a parameter with your query, but your query has no parameters. Since you have no parameters, you also do not need `$stmt=$this->o_db->prepare($sql);`.

Your code should then be:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM account.account";
$stmt=$this->o_db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: "How can I check it appears twice and keep the email address from the database in the foreach loop?" this code does not check if a email appears twice

Comment: I dont think this is what the OP was actually asking

Comment: I took it to mean "If it's there twice, keep it in the loop only once", but who knows - What else could it mean? @RiggsFolly

Comment: yea the question is pretty confusing..the topicstarter should ideally provide a mcve

Comment: what about addressing why their code is failing? They're not using a placeholder in the query. Fearing this could also be a ride into a deep rabbit hole.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah I'll mention that

Comment: Yeah , this is .. thank you! EDIT: I forgot to remove array from execute

Comment: @RaymondNijland Looks like my interpretation may have been correct

Comment: Indeed where did you buy your crystal ball? I also want one

Comment: @RaymondNijland I found it at a garage sale 